# TextChanged event triggers multiple times

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, event-handling, textchanged

I am working on android app for **Honeywell EDA51** (barcode scanner).
On certain pages in entry field I want to make it work for both scanning with **EDA51** and manual typing (character by character)

When I tried using `Completed()` event, I get good functionality for manual typing but while scanning it has problem because it always request from user to manually complete input (press **✓**)

Then I implemented it using `TextChanged()` event where I ignore (just concatenate) input until it reach certain length.

```
private void ProductBarcodeEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var entry = (Entry)sender;
        entry.TextChanged -= ProductBarcodeEntry_TextChanged;
        try
        {
            var context = (DescriptionViewModel)this.BindingContext;
            if (context.controlValue%4 == 0)
            {
                context.controlValue = 1;
                context.Barcode = context.BarcodeProduct;
                bool p = context.ExecuteScanCommand().Result;
                if (!p)
                {
                    this.ProductBarcodeEntry.Text = context.Barcode;
                    this.ProductBarcodeEntry.CursorPosition = context.Barcode.Length;
                }
                else 
                {
                    this.BoxBarcodeEntry.Text = context.BoxID;
                    this.ProductBarcodeEntry.Text = "";
                    this.ProductBarcodeEntry.Focus();
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
            context.controlValue++;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
        finally
        {
            entry.TextChanged += ProductBarcodeEntry_TextChanged; 
        }
```

Those control values are something I tried to catch how much times does it triggers event. At first I thought it fires when ever in this code I manipulate with `this.ProductBarcodeEntry.Text` but when I follow execution in debugger it doesn't recall event when it reach that point, it goes normal to the final segment and after that it starts again. I got about 4 calls but to be honest at some point both device and debugger just doesn't respond, somewhere inside code when it is stopped on some breakpoint after step over it just ignore rest of breakpoints, and device after some times do what it was supposed.

```
private void BoxBarcodeEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var entry = (Entry)sender;
        entry.TextChanged -= BoxBarcodeEntry_TextChanged;
        try
        {
            var context = (DescriptionViewModel)this.BindingContext;
            if (context.controlValue == 0)
            {
                context.controlValue = 1;
                context.Barcode = context.BarcodeBox;
                bool p = context.ExecuteScanCommand().Result;
                //bool p = context.ScanCommand.Execute(this);
                if (!p)
                {
                    this.BoxBarcodeEntry.Text = context.Barcode;
                    this.BoxBarcodeEntry.CursorPosition = context.Barcode.Length;
                }
                else 
                {
                    this.BoxBarcodeEntry.Text = context.BoxID;
                    this.ProductBarcodeEntry.Text = "";
                    this.ProductBarcodeEntry.Focus();
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
        finally
        {
            entry.TextChanged += BoxBarcodeEntry_TextChanged;
            

        }
    }
```

And **XAML** part

```
    <Entry Grid.Row="2" TextChanged="BoxBarcodeEntry_TextChanged" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="BoxBarcodeEntry" Placeholder="Scan box barcode" Text="{Binding input.BarcodeBox, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="#2A5B90" WidthRequest="300"/>
    <Entry Grid.Row="1" TextChanged="ProductBarcodeEntry_TextChanged" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="ProductBarcodeEntry" Placeholder="Scan product barcode" Text="{Binding input.BarcodeProduct, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="#2A5B90" WidthRequest="300"/>
```

`BoxBarcodeEntry_TextChanged()` is not done, its not frequently used as product and it was useless to do same thing when product scan doesn't work well
(Just for reference it never goes to this method even when `BoxBarcodeEntry.Text` is changed from `ProductBarcodeEntry_TextChanged()`).

Functionality that I want to achieve is to have two entry fields on page, focus will be on product box because some of product doesn't have box attached to it, but anyway when user scan barcode it validates (if description is about product with box, then if it is box code it stores value in `BoxBarcodeEntry`, and save it in memory, then after that until next `BoxBarcode` is scanned it makes pairs (**Box**,**Products**) etc).

Description of products with box example: (shorts **bb** - `BoxBarcode`, **pb** - `ProductBarcode` )

Scans:

- **pb1** - ignores it (**bb** in memory is **null**), and clear text field
- **bb1** - store in memory and fills `BoxBarcodeEntry.Text`
- **bb2** - store (replace old) in memory and fills `BoxBarcodeEntry.Text`
- **pb2** - pairs with **bb** from memory -> (**bb2**,**pb2**) is stored somewhere in DB
- **pb3** - pairs with **bb** from memory -> (**bb2**,**pb3**) is stored somewhere in DB
- ...

And example of description for products without box

- **pb1** - (**null**,**pb1**) is stored in DB
- **bb1** - ignored
- **bb2** - ignored
- **pb2** - (**null**,**pb2**) is stored in DB
- **pb3** - (**null**,**pb3**) is stored in DB
- ...

Maybe I wrote too much information but main question remains same, why does it triggers those events multiple times and how to prevent (or control) that behavior.

Comment: most barcode scanners can be configured to send a CR (or other keycode) when a scan completes.  Check the manual

Comment: Don't have manual but will try to find it online, that would enable me to use `Completed()` event

Comment: look at "Suffix" in the "UEMConnect Users Guide"

Comment: Found it but, I am not sure how to add suffix, or better say where I can find setting where I enable **\n** or **\t**

Comment: https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-add-remove-a-suffix-on-an-Android-device-running-CommonES-version-3-or-greater

Comment: Finally made it work, now I can use `Completed()` event. Thank you very much. I am curious, I still don't understand why `TextChanged()` event triggers multiple times (I don't need that event now but would like to know from point of knowledge)